# Suma de ambas diagonales de una matriz

Tags: python

Aquí el código:

```
M = []
cont = 1
for fila in range(5): # Matriz de 5x5.
    M.append([])
    for columna in range(5):
      M[fila].append(columna)
      M[fila][columna] = cont
      cont = cont + 1
      
for fila in range (5) :
    for columna in range (5) :
        print(str.rjust(str(M[fila][columna]), 4), end = "")
    print(); print()
input()
# Diagonal que parte en (0,0)
Sumar1 = 0; 
for fila in range(5):
    for columna in range(5):
        if fila == columna : # Va aumentando
            Sumar1 = Sumar1 + M[fila][columna]
print("Suma de diagonal que inicia en fila 1 columna 1 ", Sumar1)
```

Puedo calcular la diagonal que empieza en [0,0] hasta [4,4] pero no la siguiente... que comenzaria en [0,4]. Es decir, me faltaria calcular otra diagonal.
No logro hacerlo usando el el bucle for asi que agradeceria su ayuda.

Comment: lo tienes que hacer desde 0 o puedes usar algun modulo?

Comment: Tiene que ser desde 0. Osea, sin biblioteca, numpy, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener la diagonal principal simplemente se hace accediendo a su posición en `[i][i]`, pero para la diagonal secundaria no es así. Podemos ayudarnos de los índices negativos para acceder a elementos iniciando desde el ultimo, en este caso sería `[i][-i-1]`. Para esta basta con un solo `for` (ósea no anidados).

Puedes hacer esto con un solo `for` que recorra la matriz en un rango (`2n`) e ir cambiando el valor de `i` para obtener la diagonal principal o secundaria según la iteración. Para tu ejemplo.

```py
#creamos la matriz
M = []
cont = 1
for fila in range(5): # Matriz de 5x5.
    M.append([])
    for columna in range(5):
      M[fila].append(columna)
      M[fila][columna] = cont
      cont = cont + 1

#obtenemos las diagonales
suma = 0 
for d in range(len(M)*2):
    #e vale un numero si es menor de la longitud de la matriz
    #en caso contrario vale la ultima posición de la matriz
    e = d if d<len(M) else len(M)-d-1 #equivalente a ".. else len(M)*2-d-1"

    #d vale un numero si es menor de la longitud de la matriz
    #en caso contrario se "reinicia" valiendo d-len(M)
    d = d-len(M) if d > len(M)-1 else d 

    diag = M[d][e]
    print(diag) #imprimimos
    suma +=diag #sumamos
print(f"suma:{suma}")
```

**resultado**

```
1
7
13
19
25
5
9
13
17
21
suma:130
```

Si se te hace muy confuso el uso del operador ternario y toda la sintaxis anterioir, puedes hacerlo tranquilamente con 2 ciclos `for` (por separado)

```py
suma = 0
#diagonal principal
print("diagonal principal")
for d in range(len(M)):
    diag = M[d][d]
    print(diag)
    suma +=diag

#diagonal secundaria
print("Segunda diagonal")
for d in range(len(M)):
    diag = M[d][-d-1]
    print(diag)
    suma +=diag
print(f"suma:{suma}")
```

**resultado**

```
diagonal principal
1
7
13
19
25
Segunda diagonal
5
9
13
17
21
suma:130
```

Answer (score 1):

Una solución usando generadores:

```
def diagonal(matriz, fila, columna, direccion):
    filas = len(matriz)
    columnas = len(matriz[0])
    while 0 <= fila < filas and 0 <= columna < columnas:
        yield matriz[fila][columna]
        fila += 1
        columna += 1 if direccion else -1
```

La función recibe una matriz bidimensional (lista de listas) y una posición de partida (fila, columna) que marca el extremo superior de la diagonal. La posición de partida puede ser cualquier celda en los bordes de la matriz (excepto fila inferior).

El parámetro `direccion` determina si la diagonal avanza por la derecha (`True`) o por la izquierda (`False`).

El generador retorna una elemento de la matriz a la vez y se puede usar dentro de una comprensión de listas o como parte de una ciclo for, por lo que calcular la suma de una diagonal es tan simple como:

```
suma = sum([x for x in diagonal(matriz, 0, 0, True)])
```

#### Demo

Esta demo recorre, imprime y acumula diagonales:

```
matriz = [[1,2,3,4,5,6],
          [7,8,9,0,1,2],
          [3,4,5,6,7,8],
          [9,0,1,2,3,4]
          ]


suma = 0
for x in diagonal(matriz, 0, 0, True):
    print(x)
    suma += x
print(f"Suma diagonal (0,0) = {suma}")
print()
suma = 0
for x in diagonal(matriz, 0, 4, False):
    print(x)
    suma += x
print(f"Suma diagonal (0,4) = {suma}")
print()
```

produce

```
1
8
5
2
Suma diagonal (0,0) = 32

5
0
5
0
Suma diagonal (0,4) = 10


Process finished with exit code 0
```